# How to give a role without specifying the exact name of the role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if there was a way to self-assign roles without having to specify the exact name of the role. For instance, if I wanted the role 'D.Bch.100', I could just write 'bch' and still get the role. Here's my code:

```
@client.command(name = "giverole", aliases = ["giveroles"])
async def giverole(ctx, *, rolename):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=rolename)
    user = ctx.message.author
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.channel.send("Done! Added " + rolename + (" role to {0.author.mention}. Enjoy it!").format(ctx))
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing like that but why don't you just mention the role?

Comment: Some role names in the server are long and some users just don't write them correctly. I've seen other bots accepting partial names, that's why I asked.

Comment: Maybe they changed in the code like `if rolename == 'bch': return D.Bch.100`. But this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for-loop` (or alternatively a `regex`) to iterate over all roles & their names, and check if the entered string is anywhere in the name. Do keep in mind that this *will* match another role unintentionally, as for example `te` is in both `test` and `testing`. You could force a minimum query length optionally, but that also doesn't make sure this doesn't happen. You can also prevent this issue & show a list of all matched roles, asking the user which one they want.

```
@client.command(name = "giverole", aliases = ["giveroles"])
async def giverole(ctx, *, rolename):
    role_to_give = None
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        if rolename in role.name.lower():
            role_to_give = role # found it
            break
    if role_to_give is None:
        # no role contains their query in the name
    else:
        await user.add_roles(role)
await ctx.channel.send("Done! Added " + role_to_give.name + (" role to {0.author.mention}. Enjoy it!").format(ctx))
```

Casting the role name to lowercase to make it work case insensitively.

Though I do strongly recommend tagging a role instead, as was suggested in the comments. Unlike what you mentioned in a comment, roles having long names should not pose an issue, as Discord provides suggestions based on what you're typing, so typing part of it should already bring it up. You can even use a built-in `converter` to instantly get the `role` instance as well.

```
@client.command(name = "giverole", aliases = ["giveroles"])
async def giverole(ctx, *, rolename: discord.Role):
    await ctx.author.add_roles(rolename)
    await ctx.send("Added " + rolename.name)
```

Also, you don't have to use `ctx.message.author` to get the author, `ctx.author` works as well & is a bit shorter.

Lastly, I don't fully understand why you're using format strings while still concatenating them? It kind of defeats the purpose of using a format string in the first place. `string_a + string_b + string_c.format(d)` might as well be `"string_a {} {}".format(string_b, string_d)`.

Comment: I, too, prefer tagging the role, but this was a request from the owner of the server, and I couldn't convince him. Thanks for the input! As for the last part, you're totally right. I really can't say why I didn't do it in the first place (I probably added the second part later and didn't realize I could include the rolename in the format) but I'm going to change it. Thanks again!